# How to reduce cubic equation's maximum peak (fitting)

Tags: r, excel, curve-fitting, vertex

The ventilation volume data were collected according to the efficiency. Several samples were taken and fitted into cubic equations. 
It was written in Excel, and a third regression equation was obtained.

[image: Click to see picture]

However, as you can see from the picture, the ventilation volume at 90-95% is higher than 100%. The data should never be higher than 100%, but the maximum vertex of the auto regression is convex so that it exceeds 100% in the form of a curve.

Is there a way to reduce the maximum vertex and fit it? Use the measured data as it is, but do not exceed 100%.

The use of R or other statistical programs is also welcome. 
R values ​​can be a little lower.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas in R:

First, I'm making some example data that are similar to yours and fitting a linear model with x^3, x^2, and x as predictors:

```
#  make example data
xx = rep(c(30, 50, 70, 100), each = 10)
yy = 1/(1+exp(-(xx-50)/15))  * 4798.20 + rnorm(length(xx), sd = 20)
xx = c(0, xx)
yy = c(0, yy)

# fit third-order linear model
m0 = lm(yy ~ I(xx^3) + I(xx^2) + xx)

x_to_predict = data.frame(xx = seq(0, 100, length.out = length(xx)))
lm_preds = predict(m0, newdata = x_to_predict)
```

Idea 1: You could fit a model that uses a sigmoid (or other monotonic) curve.

```
# fit quasibinomial model for proportion
# first scale response variable between 0 and 1
m1 = glm(I(yy/max(yy)) ~ xx , family = quasibinomial())

# predict
preds_glm = predict(m1, 
                newdata = x_to_predict, 
                type = "response")
```

Idea 2: Fit a generalized additive model that will make a smooth curve.

```
# fit Generalized Additive Model
library(mgcv)
# you have to tune "k" somewhat -- larger means more "wiggliness"
m2 = gam(yy ~ s(xx, k = 4)) 
gam_preds = predict(m2, 
                    newdata = x_to_predict, 
        type = "response")
```

Here's what the plots for each model look like:

```
# plot data and predictions
plot(xx, yy, ylab = "result", xlab = "efficiency")
lines(x_to_predict$xx, 
      preds_glm*max(yy), "l", col = 'red', lwd = 2)
lines(x_to_predict$xx, 
      gam_preds, "l", col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
lines(x_to_predict$xx, lm_preds, 
      "l", col = 'black', lwd = 2, lty = 2)
legend("bottomright", 
       lty = c(0, 1, 1, 2), 
       legend = c("data", "GLM prediction", "GAM prediction", "third-order lm"), 
       pch = c(1, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
       col = c("black", "red", "blue", "black"))
```

[image: plot of three different models]

Comment: Thank you so much callin, and can i know that curve's equation?

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to StackOverflow! The generalized additive model doesn't have an equation that can be easily written out.  The generalized linear model can be written out in closed form. Here's a link to a post that describes how to write the equation from the R output [link] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20838)

Comment: @Callin please see my answer using a sigmoidal equation using data extracted from the scatterplot.

Comment: @Callin Ok. Is this okay? what if i want to get Y data from another x (ex: 34.5 %) from GAM predict. The x-axis seems to be set in 5% increments. Can we return a value in between?

Comment: Yes, you can use the fitted model to predict the result for any x value. In the code above, I created new data for prediction `x_to_predict = data.frame(xx = seq(0, 100, length.out = length(xx))`. If you want to predict the response when x = 34.5, then replace `seq(0, 100, length.out = length(xx)` with `34.5` and use the `predict` function the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted data from the scatterplot and found a good fit to a Gompertz type of sigmoidal equation "a * exp(-1.0 * exp((x - b)/c)) + Offset", with the extracted data giving parameters a = -4.7537951574153149E+03, b = 5.4531406419707224E+01, c = 2.1494180901343391E+01, and Offset = 4.4056239791186508E+03 yielding RMSE = 57.17 and R-squared = 0.9988, see below. If this seems like it might be useful to you, I suggest re-fitting the actual data using these values as the initial parameter estimates.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this. but need a time to understand.

Comment: Note that this equation has a maximum possible value, "Offset = 4.4056239791186508E+03", which appears to match the plotted curve.